Which .dll file do i choose for setting up luajit?
I'm trying to get LazyVim/NeoVim setup and I need to build with luajit, but I wasn't able to do the instructions:

Copy luajit.exe and lua51.dll (built in the src directory) to a
newly created directory (any location is ok). Add lua and lua\jit
directories below it and copy all Lua files from the src\jit
directory of the distribution to the latter directory.
There are no hardcoded absolute path names — all modules are loaded
relative to the directory where luajit.exe is installed (see
src/luaconf.h).

What i did was first install luajit from the git link and pasted into powershell, then installed cygwin and installed gcc-core and make, then made cygwin\bin go into my path for make to then work.
I tried to look online for this issue but I didn't seem to find any solution.
then i just looked up .dll, and found cyglua51.dll &  libluajit-5.1.dll.a within the luajit folder
enter image description here
Which one do i use? or do i need something that is exactly as lua51.dll instead without "cyg"?
I am not a coder/computer expert at all, I'm only really able to find quick fixes on google and can find some problems with a bit of patient, but complex problems are out of my reach.
